# Persistence in Google App Engine (Java) - accessing data outside the application

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, persistence

I'm on the process of designing a web application based on Google App Engine (Java) platform. I'm basically from *relational database world* and I'm trying to understand how to use the persistence that GAE provides.

So my questions is, in RDBMS, I can easily access my data without going through my application. i.e, I can use an SQL client to connect to my data and manipulate it. Is the same thing possible with GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both yes and no. You can open https://appengine.google.com/ and go to "Datastore Viewer". Here is a possibility to write a GQL query. But you will not be able to operate data sets with more than 500 records and with offset >1000. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Install [AppWrench Tools](http://groups.google.co.in/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/6efcbfcfbf78624d?pli=1) plugin for eclipse. I use it. It allows you to create/edit/delete/browse your local and production datastore entities from within eclipse.